# Unity - Transform.RotateAround() + Transform.Translate() - Why is rotation offset created and how can it be fixed?

Tags: unity, transformation

I have one object orbit another with RotateAround(), then I use Translate() to move the orbiting object in the same frame in an effort to change the distance at which the object is orbiting.  This causes the rotation provided by RotateAround to drift.  How can this drift be corrected without rewriting my own RotateAround?

```
public class TestRotateAround : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    Transform orbitTarget;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 dirToTarget = (orbitTarget.position - transform.position).normalized;

        transform.RotateAround(orbitTarget.position, Vector3.forward, 10 * Time.deltaTime);

        transform.Translate(-dirToTarget * Time.deltaTime * 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your goal to make a spiral? What does the "drift" look like that you're getting instead? Have you tried changing the order of the lines so that you don't rotate between computing your translation direction and actually translating?

Comment: This code certainly makes something like a spiral, but RotateAround rotates the orbiting object on a local axis to keep those axis at the same angle relative to the object being orbited.  When you add a line to translate the orbiting object further or close to the orbited object, Rotate Around is no longer able to maintain the correct local rotation of the orbiting object and begins to drift.  I'm trying to understand why that's happening.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your description correctly. Can you share an animation demonstrating the issue?

Comment: If the orbiting object starts above the object it's set to orbit, with no Translate line, the local y axis of the orbiting object will always face away from the object it's orbiting.

If you add the Translate line, that is not true.  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, `Transform.Translate` operates in local coordinates by default, but your `dirToTarget` variable is in world coordinates.

So, you can fix this by...

1. Adding `Space.World` to your translation
2. Re-ordering your code so that you rotate *after* computing your vector and translating along it, or *before*, not in-between the two steps.

Like so:

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 dirToTarget = (orbitTarget.position - transform.position).normalized;
    // If we rotate between these two lines, then the "to target" direction we
    // computed above won't be the correct "to target" direction anymore,
    // since we've rotated around the target and it's in a different direction now.
    transform.Translate(-dirToTarget * Time.deltaTime * 2, Space.World);

    // So instead we'll do our rotation at the end.
    transform.RotateAround(orbitTarget.position, Vector3.forward, 10 * Time.deltaTime);        
}
```

Or, here's an alternative formulation with no `RotateAround`/`Translate`, showing the underlying vector & quaternion math that's going on under the hood:

```
void Update() {
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(10 * Time.deltaTime, Vector3.forward);
    transform.rotation *= rotation;

    Vector3 toTarget = (orbitTarget.position - transform.position);
    Vector3 newOffset = -toTarget - 2 * Time.deltaTime * toTarget.normalized;

    transform.position = orbitTarget.position + rotation * newOffset;
}
```

Comment: I just came to this conclusion.  Thank you very much for your help!  I understand the issue now. :)